# Проецируемая память

Tags: winapi, c++

Помогите, пожалуйста, доделать код, чтобы из цикла данные записывались в "проецируемую" (в одном процессе), а в другом процессе эта память считывалась и выводилась на экран. На 147 строке ошибка с внесением данных, а со 159 не знаю, как реализовать вывод.
Код:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <clocale>
#include <process.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

// Глобальные переменные.
int N = 20;
int A = 2;
int B = 10;
int startN = 0; // промежуток [0;endFiestN]
int endFirstN = int(N/3); // промежуток [endFiestN;endSecondN]
int endSecondN = 2*endFirstN; // промежуток [endFiestN;endN]
int endN = N;
float fi = 0;
float fiMax = 2 * 3.14;
float fiAdd = fiMax / N;
int k = 0; //флажок
HANDLE hMapFile;

float Buffer[20][3]; // "буфер"
int iB = 0; // счетчик буфера.

HANDLE hSemaphore; // Семафор для учета элементов очереди
HANDLE hWriteEvent; // Событие

void threadPrint(float fi, float x, float y){
   printf("fi = %2.1f: x = %2.1f \t\t y = %2.1f\n", fi, x, y);
}
void threadResult(int sN, int lN){
    float x, y;
    for (int i = sN; i < lN; i++){
        x = (B - A)*cos(fi) + A*cos((B - A)*(fi / A));
        y = (B - A)*sin(fi) + A*sin((B - A)*(fi / A));

        //Запись результата в буфер.
        Buffer[iB][0] = fi;
        Buffer[iB][1] = x;
        Buffer[iB][2] = y;

        fi = fi + fiAdd;
        iB++;
    }
}

unsigned __stdcall ThreadFunc1(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    WaitForSingleObject(hSemaphore,INFINITE);
    int start;
    int lastN = 1;
     if(k == 0){
        start = startN;
        lastN = endFirstN;
        threadResult(start, lastN);
        k = 1;
    } else if (k == 1){
        start = endFirstN;
        lastN = endSecondN;
        threadResult(start, lastN);
        k = 2;
    } else {
        start = endSecondN;
        lastN = endN;
        threadResult(start, lastN);
    }
    k++;
    ReleaseSemaphore(hSemaphore,1, NULL); // Увеличиваем счетчик семафора на 1.
}
unsigned __stdcall ThreadFunc2(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    WaitForSingleObject(hSemaphore,INFINITE);
    int start;
    int lastN = 1;
    if(k == 0){
        start = startN;
        lastN = endFirstN;
        threadResult(start, lastN);
        k = 1;
    } else if (k == 1){
        start = endFirstN;
        lastN = endSecondN;
        threadResult(start, lastN);
        k = 2;
    } else {
        start = endSecondN;
        lastN = endN;
        threadResult(start, lastN);
    }
    ReleaseSemaphore(hSemaphore,1, NULL); // Увеличиваем счетчик семафора на 1.
}
unsigned __stdcall ThreadFunc3(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    WaitForSingleObject(hSemaphore,INFINITE);
    int start;
    int lastN = 1;
     if(k == 0){
        start = startN;
        lastN = endFirstN;
        threadResult(start, lastN);
        k = 1;
    } else if (k == 1){
        start = endFirstN;
        lastN = endSecondN;
        threadResult(start, lastN);
        k = 2;
    } else {
        start = endSecondN;
        lastN = endN;
        threadResult(start, lastN);
    }
    k++;
    ReleaseSemaphore(hSemaphore,1, NULL); // Увеличиваем счетчик семафора на 1.
}
unsigned __stdcall ThreadPrint(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    WaitForSingleObject (hWriteEvent, INFINITE);

    int i = 0;
    while (i < N){
        float a = Buffer[i][0], b = Buffer[i][1], c = Buffer[i][2];
        threadPrint(a,b,c);
        i++;
    }

}
unsigned __stdcall ThreadWrite(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    WaitForSingleObject (hWriteEvent, INFINITE);

    ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open("Out.txt");
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
            outfile<<Buffer[i][0]<<"\t"<<Buffer[i][1]<<"\t\t"<<Buffer[i][2]<<endl;
    outfile.clear();
    }
}
unsigned __stdcall ThreadReadAndWriteToObj(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    PFLOAT pBuf;
    hMapFile = CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, 256, "MyFileMappingObject"); //Создание объекта "проекция файла".
    pBuf = (PFLOAT) MapViewOfFile(hMapFile,FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,0,0,256); //создание представления файла в адресном пространстве процесса.

////// Здесь ошибка!

    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
            float a = Buffer[i][0], b = Buffer[i][1], c = Buffer[i][2];

            CopyMemory((PFLOAT)pBuf, a, 10000);
    }
    UnmapViewOfFile(pBuf);
}
unsigned __stdcall ThreadReadAndPrint(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    printf("Из проецируемой памяти:");
////// Здесь добавить!
    LPCTSTR pBuf;
    hMapFile = OpenFileMapping(FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,FALSE,"MyFileMappingObject");
    pBuf = (LPTSTR) MapViewOfFile(hMapFile,FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,0,0,256);
    MessageBox(NULL, pBuf, TEXT("Process2"), MB_OK);

    UnmapViewOfFile(pBuf);
}
main()
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "russian");
    STARTUPINFO cif1, cif2;
    ZeroMemory(&cif1,sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi1, pi2;
    if(!CreateProcess(NULL, "MyChildProcess",NULL,NULL,FALSE,0,NULL,NULL,&cif1,&pi1)) //Процесс #1
        {
            hSemaphore=CreateSemaphore(NULL, 1, 1000, NULL); //Создаем семафор.

            LPCTSTR pBuf;
            unsigned uThreadIDs[6];
            HANDLE hThreads[6], hMapFile1, hMapFile2;

            hThreads[0] = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex( NULL, 0, &ThreadFunc1, NULL, 0,&uThreadIDs[0]);
            hThreads[1] = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex( NULL, 0, &ThreadFunc2, NULL, 0,&uThreadIDs[1]);
            hThreads[2] = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex( NULL, 0, &ThreadFunc3, NULL, 0,&uThreadIDs[2]);
            hThreads[3] = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex( NULL, 0, &ThreadPrint, NULL, 0,&uThreadIDs[3]);
            hThreads[4] = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex( NULL, 0, &ThreadWrite, NULL, 0,&uThreadIDs[4]);
            hThreads[5] = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex( NULL, 0, &ThreadReadAndWriteToObj, NULL, 0,&uThreadIDs[5]);

            WaitForMultipleObjects(3, hThreads, TRUE, INFINITE );
            CloseHandle( hSemaphore );
            CloseHandle( hThreads[0] );
            CloseHandle( hThreads[1] );
            CloseHandle( hThreads[2] );

            hWriteEvent = CreateEvent(NULL,TRUE,FALSE,TEXT("WriteEvent"));
            CloseHandle( hThreads[3] );
            CloseHandle( hThreads[4] );
            CloseHandle( hThreads[5] );
        }
            CloseHandle( pi1.hProcess);
        if(!CreateProcess(NULL, "MyChildProcess",NULL,NULL,FALSE,0,NULL,NULL,&cif2,&pi2)) //Процесс #2
        {
            unsigned uThreadIDs[1];
            HANDLE hThreads[1];
            hThreads[0] = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex( NULL, 0, &ThreadReadAndPrint, NULL, 0,&uThreadIDs[0]);
            WaitForMultipleObjects(1, hThreads, TRUE, INFINITE );
            CloseHandle( hThreads[0] );
        }
}
```

Comment: @wao138: А как эта ошибка проявляется? Что идёт неправильно?

Comment: @VladD, вроде просто последний результат, вносимый в память, заменяет предыдущий.

Comment: @wao138: с 

    float a = Buffer[i][0], b = Buffer[i][1], c = Buffer[i][2];

я проблем не вижу. В любом случае, вы можете посмотреть в отладчике, что записывается в переменные. А вот 

    CopyMemory((PFLOAT)pBuf, a, 10000);

— это что-то не то. По [документации](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366535%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), второй параметр должен быть указателем на область памяти, откуда вы копируете, а у вас что?

Comment: @VladD, изменил на:


  float* pBuf;
    hMapFile = CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, 256, "MyFileMappingObject"); //Создание объекта "проекция файла".
    pBuf = (float*) MapViewOfFile(hMapFile,FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,0,0,256); //создание представления файла в адресном пространстве процесса.

    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
            float* a; *a = Buffer[i][0];
            float* b; *b = Buffer[i][1];
            float* c; *c = Buffer[i][2];
            CopyMemory(pBuf, a, 10000);
    }

Comment: @wao138: Ааааааа! Что вы делаете? Вы заказали неинициализированный указатель `a`, который указывает фиг знает куда. И пишете по адресу, куда он указывает, содержимое буфера, в область памяти «на кого бог пошлёт». Если вам очень повезёт, это просто крешнется. Если нет, это затрёт важную структуру в памяти, и вы будете долго удивляться, почему всё глючит.

---
ЗЫ: лимит комментариев вышел, буду удалять верхние.

Comment: @VladD, как тогда правильно делать?

Comment: @wao138: Встречный вопрос: а что вы _хотите_ сделать в этом месте программы?

Comment: @VladD, я хочу записать информацию с помощью цикла в определенную часть памяти и, соответственно, вывести ее на экран в другом процессе.